# Which encoding use mysql to store data in .MYD files?

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I know I can set varables in mysql to handle utf8 (client, connection, database, results, server and system). In fact, I set all of them to utf8 (except filesystem). But when I open the *sometable*.MYD file in the data directory of the mysql folder (with textwrangler) it says that the text encoding is Western (Mac OS Roman), and displays strange characters instead of spanish accents. When I export a database to a *sometable*.sql file through mysqldump and I open it whit TextEdit, those strange characters are passed to that file (even if I put the --default-character-set to utf8).
Is there a way to make mysql to store actual utf8 characters in the .MYD files? If that's possible, is it a good practice to handle non-ascii characters in mysql?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you care what encoding is used in your MYD files?  From most people's perspective, MySQL is entitled to compress/encrypt/encode those files however it wants.

Comment: Well, I'm very curious. I'm learning mysql, I had an issue and I just thought that looking at those files I could find the answer. I realized that non-ascii characters were displaying wrong there so I just wondered why... I just like to understand things from the core.

Answer (score 0):

To see it within mysql for a database called mydb, run this

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE mydb;
```

To see it in the OS, run this

```
cd /var/lib/mysql/mydb
cat db.opt
```

If the table has different encoding in specific column you could see it for mydb.mytable with

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE mydb.mytable\G
```

If you do not see any encoding, then the tables's default should the database's encoding

Comment: Thank you Rolando. Your answer is very helpful for me, although it didn't answer exactly what I was asking. I just wonder why the actual encoding of the .MYD files of my database (that is Western Mac os Roman) is different to the one I specified when I created it (that is utf8). I have no issues with it, it's just I wonder why... as I said to eggyal, I like to understand things from the core.